# Add Https support to Linux Vm Running Docker Compose

Tags: azure, docker, ssl, virtual-machine

I just deployed on a Linux VM on Azure a docker-compose file containing asp.net core applications. Right now it's HTTP, when I call the Vm I call it via the DNS and the entry port of my ApiGateway running inside a container.
Since it's not really secure with user's informations, I was wondering what should I do :

1) Make the connection to my Vm https (how would I do that) instead of Http?
 2) Make my container https instead of http?

I've read many articles but a lot either explain how to add ssl certificate to a new vm or with IIS/Ngninx and not with a container environment.

Any help or explanations are welcome, it's really not my cup of tea...

Thanks in advance and have a great day !

Lio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up adding a ssl certificate to nginx with certbot and then redirect my http traffic to https through nginx as reverse proxy.